# Pass array to the command bus

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to understand how to use the laravel 5.0 command bus, but I am struggling to get it right, so I'm looking for help with a few questions:

I'd like to dispatch an array of memberIds to run through a loop inside the handle function of the command.

$members:

```
array:2 [
0 => "147"
1 => "148"
 ]
```

This array is sent like this:

```
$this->dispatch(new SendMail($members));
```

How do I access the array in the handle method of SendMail command?  I haven't found many examples, but nearly all of them pass $command into the handler.

```
public function handle($command)
{
  //this doesn't work
  foreach($command->members as $memberId){
   $contractor = Contractor::find($memberId);

}
```

Do I need to return anything from the handler in order to continue running the other logic inside of my original function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your trying to inject your `$members` array to your job's constructor method, you need to handle it there.

Then you'll be able to use your array in the hanle method.

```
// in your job class

protected $members;

public function __construct($members)
{
    $this->members = $members
}

public function handle ()
{
     foreach ($this->members as $member) {
         //your logic
     }
}
```

And if you want to inject an Eloquent model to your job (instead of an array) remember that you can typehint directtly in the constructor and , using the `SerializesModels` trait Laravel will retrieve it for you. This is described in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/master/queues#job-class-structure).

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. I really appreciate it.